# Spring-data TransactionTemplate read after write consistency

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have two java processes that are accessing to one mySql table one is reading the data and another one is writing. I need to put the read on wait during the writing operation.

I'm using spring-data and I tried to configure the transactionTemplate but, it seems it's not working. This is the write method:

```
public boolean upadteVisualizationTable(HashMap<String, LabResultVisualization> labResultVisualizations) {

    //use TransactionCallbackWithoutResult handler if ur query doesnt result anything
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus paramTransactionStatus) {

            try {

                logger.debug("Removing LabTestVisualization ");

                [....]

             } catch (Exception ex) {
                 logger.error("Something goes wrong on the transaction: ", ex);
                 paramTransactionStatus.setRollbackOnly();                  
             }

        }

    });

    logger.info("LabTestVisualization Table updated");
    return true;

}
```

this is the read:

```
public boolean checkPanelsExist(final String loinc) {

    return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Boolean>() {

        public Boolean doInTransaction(TransactionStatus paramTransactionStatus) {

            try {

                [...]

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return false;
            }

        }

    });

}
```

The problem is that the read operation is not during the write operation. This generate a data inconsistency. How can I tell to the read transaction to wait if the write is still running?

I tried also using @Transacional annotation but without success.

Comment: There is no typical solution where one blocks while the other finishes.  Generally the later transaction will either see all of the previous transactions updates (if it has committed) or none (if it is still in progress).  In practice databases may allow some of the updates to be visible but not all in order to increase performance.  For details, see this article on isolation levels: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-isolation-tutorial

Comment: I should also mention that, in order to implement transaction isolation many databases will use locks under the hood so it may be that sometimes a read will block on a write.  However, the details of these locks are database dependent and typically not something you should rely on.